# Want to use Drupal 8 for new product

Tags: drupal-8

I want to built my new product on Drupal 8, But I am not able to make my mind to use it b'coz of below mentioned points.

1. Drupal 8 is still in beta version
2. Many major modules for example {Libraries API, Token, Pathauto,  Date, IMCE }are still in dev version and many more vital modules are still dev version.
3. Frequently release of Core updates.

The product I am planning is not simple content side it will have lot of dynamic things in it and e-commerce too.

Why I am looking towards Drupal 8 is,  It's many new promising features, such as, symphony in base, mobile first, and many other new concept they have bring in core and obviously its a new upgraded version of Drupal.

Please give your suggestion whether should I start it with Drupal 7 or Drupal 8

Answer (score 0):

I would love to see answers from people who know Drupal better than me as well. 
The only thing I would add is: please have in mind the pain and suffering moving from Drupal 7 to 8 later on. The changes between the 2 are drastic and it will be hard to change your mind once the site in online.